# Make bootstrap carousel image and text readable in mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap carousel looks fine on desktop. The images are sized at 1200x400. But on mobile, it shrinks in so much that you can't ready the text on the images. Also, the navigation dots on the bottom of the player move up on top of the image.

1) How do I keep the size big enough to read the text on the images on mobile

2) How do I prevent the navigation dots on the bottom of the player from overlapping on my image on mobile

[image]

Here's my bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/huskydawgs/6UtgjHqm8f

Here's my html:

```
   <div class="content-section-b">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <!-- Indicators -->
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  </ol>

                  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/apple_orange_testimonials.png" alt="Apples and Oranges">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/pears_mangos_testimonials.png" alt="Pears and Mangos">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Controls -->
                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                  </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

</div>
<!-- /.content-section-b -->
```

Here's my css:

```
    .content-section-b {
    padding: 50px 0;
    background-color: #3C5A78;
}

.carousel-control.left {
    background-image:none;
}

.carousel-control.right {
    background-image:none;
}
```

Comment: Use `media queries` to display only one image on mobile view, which will be larger in size.

Comment: Can you show me in a bootply or jsfiddle?

Comment: 2) How do I prevent the navigation dots on the bottom of the player from overlapping on my image on mobile

Comment: The apple and orange image is one image because the client wanted to show two testimonials at a time.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao is correct. Displaying two images in mobile will result in smaller visibility. You have to use one testimonial only. (Nothing to do with code, but general screen size issue)

Comment: The text in the image is not comfortable to read even in desktops.. Better get good quality images where font looks good or you can use containers and type in text with media queries as said above

Comment: Then its quite difficult in your case. Whole design has to be changed. You could have implemented the client's requirement in slight different way. Showing 2 images as separate in desktop view and one image mobile view. The answer would be much more longer in this case..

Comment: How would I show 2 separate images in desktop view and one image in mobile view?

Comment: @user3075987 check my answer, it answers all your questions

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the source images: they make it seem as if they were two different carousel items, when are in fact only one (apple-orange & pear-mango)... For a quick fix, you could make individual images from the sources (one for each fruit), hide the regular carousel through media queries on xs screens, and have a visible-xs carousel which has 4 instead of 2 carousel items.

It's not a great solution, though.

Fast example: http://www.bootply.com/U5uYwmnt1g

**EDIT**

Added the CSS to move the navigation dots on mobile not to overlap with the slides.

Expanding on why it's not the best solution:

-You should make the elements of the carousel be html elements, for a start, and not rely completely on images with shapes and text inside (everything on your images can be replicated easily with CSS, using images only for the fruits, or for the fruits *and* the cirle, if you don't care to make the circle with CSS)

-Once this is done, you could skip the 2nd carousel and modify the content of each slide through media queries (or helper classes) to get the desired result

-The CSS for the navigation dots uses the `max-width` query, which I understand is not usually recomended, though in this case it might be well used (if somebody can expand on this, please do)